# Java multiple keypresses

Tags: java, key, awt, keypress, keylistener

Is there a simple way to check multiple keypresses at once? I walk using :

```
    this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() 
    {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0)
        {
            if(arg0.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            {
                if (checkMovement(-1, user.getFalling()))
                {
                    user.move("left");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

and want to be able to hold a button to 'sprint' while moving. I tried using another KeyListener with checking for another key, then using the method "user.sprint()", but it would not recognize two keypresses at once.

Is there any easy way to check for if a key is down? I do have multiple threads running, could I put some sort of if-statement in the thread to check if it is pressed when the thread loops?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For your `move` key, what you are doing is fine.

For your sprint button, use `KeyAdapter#keyPressed` to record when the key has been pressed down and `KeyAdapter#keyReleased` to record when the key has been released (store it in a `boolean`, for example).

Then when your move event happens, check the boolean to see if you are walking or sprinting.  For example, here is a key adapter which records which keys are currently pressed down.

```
Set<Integer> pressed = new HashSet<>();
this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0) {
            pressed.add(arg0.getKeyCode());
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
            pressed.remove(arg0.getKeyCode());
        }
    });
// if pressed.contains(keyCode), that key is currently being held
```

Comment: I've tried that, but unless I just did it wrong, whenever I press the second button, it cancels the holding-down-button move button, so you have to press the arrow key again. Is there a way to get around this? Did I do it wrong?

Comment: @user3838829 You probably did it wrong, though as you have not posted that code I can't really comment further.  You should probably also use the `keyTyped` event for detecting your non-held button.

Comment: My attempt to this was : [link](http://prntscr.com/42re1f). It still requires the person to press Enter first to sprint, then move with the arrow keys. Pressing arrow keys, then enter, however, stops the player from running still

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution I like quite a bit. Incase anyone else wants to see how I did it, I will post code below :)

```
this.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() 
    {
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent arg0)
        {
            if(arg0.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            {
                if (!world.user.moving()) if (world.checkMovement(-1)) world.user.move("left");
            }
            if(arg0.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            {
                if (!world.user.moving()) if (world.checkMovement(1)) world.user.move("right");
            }                   
            if (arg0.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            {
                world.user.jump();
            }   
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0)
        {
            if(arg0.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            {
                world.user.move("left","stop");
            }                                   
            if (arg0.getKeyCode()==KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            {
                world.user.move("right","stop");
            }
        }
    });
```

Basically, the key presses only set the direction of movement of the player. To stop the player, it checks for if you released the key in the direction you were going.